# React Native Flatlist Only last item is updated

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

when I try to update the data in the flatlist it doesn't update the selected item but instead only updates the last item that was inserted.

Update:

```
    const updateUser = (item) => {
        setModalVisible(false);
        let jobRef = firebase.database().ref("user/" + userId + "/job/" + item.id);
        jobRef
            .update({ name: newName})
            .then(res => console.log(res))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    };
```

keyExtractor and renderItem

```
const keyExtractor = (item, index) => index.toString();
const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
        return (
           <View>
                <Modal visible={modalVisible}>
                    <View style={styles.modal}>
                        <TextInput
                            onChangeText={text => setNewName(text)} />
                                <TouchableOpacity
                                    onPress={() => setModalVisible(false)} style={styles.button}>
                                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
                                        Cancel
                                    </Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <TouchableOpacity
                                    onPress={() => updateUser(item)} style={styles.button}>
                                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
                                        Confirm
                                    </Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </Modal>
                <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => { setModalVisible(true)}}>
               </View>
           </View>
        );
    };
```

flatlist

```
<FlatList
                  keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
                  data={menus}
                  renderItem={renderItem}
        />
```

For example, I click the item in the flatlist I want to edit. It opens up a modal. I input the new data in the textInput. It updates the last inserted item instead of the one I selected. I think the keyExtractor is what helps select the item in the flatlist but I don't see anything wrong with my keyExtractor.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is because all your modals share the same `modalVisible` state (if not, please update your code snippet). If that is the case, try refactoring your code so that there is just one modal, rendered outside of the `FlatList`, and then add an `item`/`setItem` state to specify which item the modal should update. Set this item from your list items.

You could also use `item`/`setItem` to control modal visibility (show when item is set, then set it to null when hiding the modal).